# How much of the Razer Synapse configuration is stored on the device itself?

Tags: linux, razer-mouse, razer-keyboard, razer-synapse

I have a couple Razer Chroma devices and a couple regular Razer devices (2 mice, 1 keyboard, 1 mouse pad). If it matters I can give specifics.

I want to switch to Linux as I hate the imbued marketing drive in Win10 despite being a good overall gaming platform. There are of course a lot of little considerations in actually making the switch.

Since there is no native Linux support for Razer Synapse, what will I be losing in using a bunch of Razer products in Linux? Razer has some amount of on-device storage as well as cloud syncing.

**Primary concerns:**

- Will color profiles persist? (Chroma only)
- Will DPI settings persist?
- Will the "Turn off device lights when displays are off" setting persist?

**Secondary concerns:**

- Will button configurations persist?
- Will macros persist?

Comment: have you tried loading up a linux virtual machine, connect the mouse, and tested it yourself?

Comment: I had considered it but I have not tried it as I am not sure the VM would ever truly take exclusive control of the devices. I would think that since they were booted with Windows initially, they would be set up as synapse dictates (however much that is). I'm not familiar enough with how the host passes mouse/keyboard commands to the guest.

Comment: Sure it would;  When you connect a USB device to a virtual machine it is disconnected from the host OS.  I suggest you try it, or a live environment, to get the general capabilities of the mouse within Linux.  As for the features of the device and/or driver that entirely is based on the Linux driver.

Comment: Ok good to know. I think I'll just go straight to the live environment since that is typically even easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, the color settings and DPI settings are handled entirely in the mouse, while the other mentioned settings are handled by the drivers on Windows.

That being said, I was only able to test this out using a single mouse (a Razer DeathAdder Chroma). I suppose it is possible that other devices handle their settings differently.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do the keyboard on a virtual machine either because the virtual machine can only recognize hardware on the system, not software.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people ask. It seems you submitted an answer without actually answering the question. You should've posted a comment instead. Unfortunately, this is not possible when you have less than 50 reputation points. [Here's why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/298071). Please remove your answer and try to earn some reputation so you can comment.